# Instance variables are nil after I try to set them

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

can't understand what's wrong here. I want to set some instance variables for view controller:

```
    private func simpleViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController! {
    let controller: SimpleTutorialController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SimpleTutorialController") as! SimpleTutorialController
    let mainText = "simple_main_\(index + 1)".localized
    let detailText = "simple_detail_\(index + 1)".localized
    print(mainText)
    print(detailText)
    controller.mainText? = mainText
    controller.detailText? = detailText
    print(controller.mainText)
    print(controller.detailText)
    return controller
}
```

and in logs I see something strange:

```
Aprendizagem
Palavra
nil
nil
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: How SimpleTutorialController is defined? Are mainText and detailText strong referenced?

Comment: @reviver as far as I know variables in swift are strong by default, SimpleController  is taken from Storyboard and than appearing in PageViewController

Comment: What is `.localized`? As far as I am aware, `String` doesn't have anything called `localized`

Comment: @Phoen1xUK return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")

Comment: Change `controller.mainText?` to `controller.mainText` and similar for `controller.detailText?`. I assume they are both `String?`

Comment: @Phoen1xUK it works! Can u give some explanations?

Comment: When referring to them, you don't need to add the optional operator, if they are already set to optional variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `controller.mainText?` to `controller.mainText` and similar for `controller.detailText?`.

When referring to optional variables, you don't need the `?` when accessing them. You can use it when the variable is already set, but it is still not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you mean assigning the text variables without the question marks like this:

```
controller.mainText = mainText
controller.detailText = detailText
```

If you have the question marks the assignment only succeeds when the variable, in this case mainText, is not nil. It failed just because it was nil and thus stayed nil.